# Does stopPropagation() stops executing the event from capture phase?

Tags: javascript, dom

This image is taken from **DOM ENLIGHTENMENT** book. It says stopPropagation() will stop the capture and bubble event flow phases.

[image: DOM enlightment book snippet]

> I know **stopPropagation()** will stop propagation and won't execute the callback function in the bubbling phase.

But in the following code snippet after using the **stopPropagation()** on the button, the body event callback method is still executed.

Does **stopPropagation()** also stop the event flow phase in the capture phase also?

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button');

document.body.addEventListener('click', e => {
  console.log('Body event triggered');
}, true);

button.addEventListener('click', e => {
  console.log('button is clicked 1');
});

button.addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log('button is clicked 2');
});

button.addEventListener('click', e => {
  console.log('button is clicked 3');
});
```

```html
<button> click me </button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But in the following code snippet after using the stopPropagation() on the button, the body event callback method is still executed.

All your `button` `click` handlers are target/bubbling handlers, not capture handlers. At the point you're calling `stopPropagation`, the capture phase is already done. If you had a target/bubbling handler on `document.body`, you'd see that it wasn't called.

Note that propagation relates to moving from one element to its parent (bubbling) or descendant (capture) but doesn't affect processing other handlers on the *same* element, which is why your handler calling `stopPropgation` didn't stop the other handlers on `button` *both* firing. (If you'd used `stopImmediatePropagation`, you would have stopped the third handler because it stops things right away, even in the middle of the current element's handlers.)

Here's an example cancelling propagation during the capture phase:

```js
const div = document.getElementById("middle");
const button = document.getElementById("button");

// Capture phase on body
document.body.addEventListener("click", e => {
    console.log("body capture handler");
}, true);

// Target/bubbling phase on body
document.body.addEventListener("click", e => {
    console.log("body target/bubbling handler");
});

// Capture phase on middle
middle.addEventListener("click", e => {
    console.log("middle capture handler - stopping propagation");
    e.stopPropagation();
}, true);

// Target/bubbling phase on middle
middle.addEventListener("click", e => {
    console.log("middle target/bubbling handler");
});

// Capture phase on button
button.addEventListener("click", e => {
    console.log("button capture handler");
}, true);

// Target/bubbling phase on button
button.addEventListener("click", e => {
    console.log("button target/bubbling handler");
});
```

```html
<div id="middle">
    <input type="button" id="button" value="Click me">
</div>
```

Notice that:

1. The capture phase handler on `button` didn't fire, because propagation was stopped before it got there; and
2. None of the target/bubbling phase handlers fired, since propagation was stopped before the target phase (and thus before the bubbling phase).

I find this diagram from the [DOM3 Events spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-flow) really useful for picturing this stuff:

[image]

Comment: I've used `true` as a third parameter to `addEventListener` for `capturing` phase. But it still runs. Is it because it has already processed before the `e.stopPropagation()` on `button`

Comment: @DeC - Yes, that's what I'm saying in the second sentence of the answer ("At the point you're calling stopPropagation, the capture phase is already done.") In the diagram above, you start with the topmost red arrow. As you can see, the third arrow takes you to `body` which is when your capture phase handler on `body` runs. Then capture continues until it reaches your `button` (in the diagram it's a `td`). Then each of your `button` handlers runs, and the middle one stops propagation. That means that none of the green arrows happens, but the red ones already have.